# Portmanteau in Middle Egyptian

Tags: grammar

coming here redirected from the history stack.

Lacking a proper literal translation for the word benedict in the language –as in "well spoken (of)–", I figured the best would be to create it by joining the words

[xn nfr] good {Aa1 N35 Y1 F35}

and

[mdw] (v.) speak, address (someone){S43 D46 G43 A2} 
(or one of its variations).

Now however, how should one approach the merging of the words? Can't find much info on the subject.
Thanks in advance.

P.S.: This is the dictionary I'm using:

www.pyramidtextsonline.com/documents/DicksonDictionary.pdf

Comment: This question is too language-specific, and I'm afraid that we simply have no users who could answer it.

Comment: I could suggest checking out Antonio Loprieno book on Egyptian as a starting point, I found it a good read.

Comment: @bytebuster that doesn't seem to be a legitimate reason to close this. However, to me the question is entirely unclear. 'How do you approach?' that's too broad or vague or I just don't know.